# Storing and Accessing 2D array in another array C

Tags: c

I am working in C. (not C++)

I have the following code (simplified for the purpose of the question):

```
const unsigned char val[2][4] = 
{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
};
const unsigned char** container[2] = 
{ 
    val,
    val
};

print(container[0][0][0]);
```

My expectation is that this would print 1, but it doesn't (it prints 0 but I think that is just what happens to be at that memory address).

I would expect this `print(container[0][1][2]);` to print 7. It does not either.

My intention is to define a bunch of 2D arrays somewhere, and then store any array of all those 2D arrays for access elsewhere.

Comment: And what did you do with all the warnings you got from your compiler? Ignored them?

Comment: No warnings I'm afraid. However I am building for a 30 year old machine (Nintendo NES), compiling with CC65, so perhaps if I try this on a more modern environment I would get better compiler feedback?

Comment: Use a standard C compiler. This code was invalid C 30 years ago as well.

Comment: @Lundin It literally compiles and runs, as I said.

Comment: It would appear that your compiler is broken then. Use a standard compliant one released after 1989 or later.

Comment: Btw if this is intended to be used by a heavily resource-restrained 8 bitter you definitely don't want to allocated unnecessary "pointer bloat tables", but access the arrays directly. Writing C code for such systems is _hard_ and you need detailed C knowledge for it. It is far easier to code them in assembler, because then what you see is what you get.

Comment: Yah, I'm on an NES with 16KB of fixed program memory + 128KB of bankable memory (swapping in 16KB at a time). It's been quite an adjustment from my day job :D

I'll likely stick with this for now, since it makes the most sense to me, and come back to it if memory because an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned char val[2][4] = 
{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
};
const unsigned char** container[1] = { val };

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", container[0][0][0]);
}
```

and

```
% gcc val.c      
val.c:8:40: warning: initialization of ‘const unsigned char **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘const unsigned char (*)[4]’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    8 | const unsigned char** container[1] = { val };
      |                                        ^~~
val.c:8:40: note: (near initialization for ‘container[0]’)
```

and

```
% ./a.out        
[1]    228086 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

An array name that undergoes value conversion becomes a pointer to the *first element*. The first element of `val` is `val[0]`, a pointer to it is `&val[0]` and it has type `const unsigned char (*)[4]`. A two-dimensional array does not specifically decay to a doubly-indirect pointer.

The correct declaration for `container` would have been (here for 3, not 1 pointers to provide an example:

```
const unsigned char (*container[3])[4] = { val, val, val };
```

If in doubt you can use [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=declare+container+as+array+3+of+pointer+to+array+4+of+const+unsigned+char).

---

Most of the time it could be simply

```
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned char val[2][4] = 
{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
};

const unsigned char (*container)[4] = val;

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", container[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I want to store an array of "val" (see my original question, updated to reflect this requirement more clearly)

Comment: Thank you so much. That is really helpful. I got it working in a modern compiler, but unfortunately it doesn't work in CC65/NES (my target platform). Will need to dig into why that is, but at least I have a working example now.

Comment: It was just giving unexpected values when I accessed the array. Turned out to be a bug in my rendering code which I used to print the values of I was getting out of the array. Fixed that and everything is good to go. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
const unsigned char** container[1]
```

will give you an array (with just one element) of "pointers to pointer to unsigned".

A "pointer to pointer to unsigned" can't be used with array indexing because the array dimension isn't known when you only have such a pointer.

What you want is probably:

```
const unsigned char (*container)[4] =  val;
```

This makes `containter` a pointer to an array of 4 unsigned. Now the inner-dimension is known so you can use array indexing like:

```
printf("%d\n", container[0][0]);
printf("%d\n", container[1][2]);
```

**EDIT**

If you really want an array of these, you can do:

```
const unsigned char valA[2][4] = 
{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
};

const unsigned char valB[2][4] = 
{
    { 11, 12, 13, 14 },
    { 15, 16, 17, 18 },
};

const unsigned char (*container[2])[4] =  {valA, valB};

printf("%d\n", container[0][0][0]);
printf("%d\n", container[0][1][2]);
printf("%d\n", container[1][0][0]);
printf("%d\n", container[1][1][2]);
```

Comment: Thanks! But one of the requirements (maybe I over simplified my example) is that I store an array of these. So going back to my original example (which I will update), I would change the initialization of container to:

const unsigned char** container[2] = { val, val };